# How can I force this expression into a given form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This problem has been irritating me, and conceptually, it should be very straight forward! This equation is derived from a circuit with a dependent voltage source; it describes the gain.

$ G(\omega)=\huge\frac{\mu}{1+\frac{R_0}{R_L}}\frac{\frac{R_i}{1+j\omega C_iR_i}}{R_s+\frac{R_i}{1+j\omega C_iR_i}}$

Here's the goal: Express this equation on the form of

$G(\omega)=K\large\frac{1}{1+j\beta \omega}$

where $K$ and $\beta$ are simply variable representations of some expression - this is just a general form or "wrapper" if you will.

It is obvious that the first fraction in the first expression will be contained in $K$. The simplification will therefore be applied to the second fraction. The problem that I encounter is in regard to $\large R_s$. My first inclination is to multiply the numerator and denominator by

$\large \frac{1+j\omega C_iR_i}{R_i}$.

When I do, I am left with

$G(\omega)=K\LARGE\frac{1}{\frac{R_s}{R_i}+j\omega C_iR_s+1}$

Now I have three terms on the bottom - close, but not of the proper form. There probably is a very simple solution that I am missing for some reason. Any constructive input is appreciated.

NOTE: $j$ is the same as $i$ - an imaginary number.

Comment: Hint: if your calculations are correct, from the last expression's denominator factor out $1+\frac{R_s}{R_i}$ and absorb it in $K$.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't see that. It is so obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

$$
K = G\pars{0} = {\mu \over 1 + R_{0}/R_{L}}\,{R_{i} \over R_{s} + R_{i}}
\quad\imp\quad
G\pars{\omega}
=
K\,{R_{s} + R_{i} \over R_{i}}\,
{R_{i} \over R_{s} + R_{i} + jR_{s}C_{i}R_{i}\omega}
$$

$$
G\pars{\omega}
=
K\pars{R_{s} + R_{i}}\,
{1 \over R_{s} + R_{i} + jR_{s}C_{i}R_{i}\omega}
=
K\,
{1 \over 1 + j\bracks{R_{s}C_{i}R_{i}/\pars{R_{s} + R_{i}}}\omega}
$$

\begin{align}\vphantom{\Huge A}&\end{align}
$${\large%
G\pars{\omega}
=
{K \over 1 + j\beta \omega}\,,
\qquad
K \equiv {\mu \over 1 + R_{0}/R_{L}}\,{R_{i} \over R_{s} + R_{i}}\,,\qquad
\beta \equiv {R_{s}C_{i}R_{i} \over R_{s} + R_{i}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the denominator of your last expression as $(1+R_s/R_i) + j\omega C_iR_s$, which is a constant times $1 + j\omega (C_iR_s/(1+R_s/R_i))$.